# Error parsing XML:mismatched tag/ Button cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I was recently adding in a button into my program with in some java code and it could resolve the data type so as usual I save, built, and cleaned it. When I did that all of my Android ids and the majority of my XML forms started having errors.

Here is one of the XML forms.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/background">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ACBonus"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Armor Class Bonus" 
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ACType"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Armor Class Type" 
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ACCheckPenalty"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Armor Check Penalty" 
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ACSpellFailure"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Armor Class Spell Failure" 
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ACWeight"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Armor Class Weight" 
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ACProperties"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Armor Class Properties" 
            android:textColor="#FFFF00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
        </TextView>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bACDescriptionSave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Save" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the java class I was working in at the time.

```
package com.example.pathfinderapprentice;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WeapDescrip extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    TextView Weapon, WeapAttackBonus, WeapCrit, WeapType, WeapRange, WeapAmmo,
            WeapDamage, Save;
    FileOutputStream WeaponStuff;
    String FILENAME = "InteralString";
    PopUp PopUp = new PopUp();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.weapdescrip);
        setIds();
        loadData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent W = new Intent(WeapDescrip.this, PopUp.class);
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Weapon:
            /*
             * String data = "Test"; File f = new File(FILENAME); try {
             * WeaponStuff = new FileOutputStream(f); WeaponStuff.close(); }
             * catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch
             * block e.printStackTrace(); } catch (IOException e) { // TODO
             * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); }
             * 
             * try { WeaponStuff = openFileOutput(FILENAME,
             * Context.MODE_PRIVATE); WeaponStuff.write(data.getBytes());
             * WeaponStuff.close(); } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // TODO
             * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } catch
             * (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             * e.printStackTrace(); }
             */
            startActivity(W);
            String WeaponName = PopUp.savedObject;
            break;
        case R.id.WeapAttackBonus:
            startActivity(W);
            String WeaponAttackBonus = PopUp.savedObject;
            break;
        case R.id.WeapCrit:
            startActivity(W);
            String WeaponCritical = PopUp.savedObject;
            break;
        case R.id.WeapType:
            startActivity(W);
            String WeaponType = PopUp.savedObject;
            break;
        case R.id.WeapRange:
            startActivity(W);
            String WeaponRange = PopUp.savedObject;
            break;
        case R.id.WeapAmmuniton:
            startActivity(W);
            String WeaponAmmo = PopUp.savedObject;
            break;
        case R.id.WeapDamage:
            startActivity(W);
            String WeaponDamage = PopUp.savedObject;
            break;
        }
    }

    public void setIds() {
        Weapon = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Weapon);
        WeapAttackBonus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WeapAttackBonus);
        WeapCrit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WeapCrit);
        WeapType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WeapType);
        WeapRange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WeapRange);
        WeapAmmo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WeapAmmuniton);
        WeapDamage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.WeapDamage);
        Weapon.setOnClickListener(this);
        WeapAttackBonus.setOnClickListener(this);
        WeapCrit.setOnClickListener(this);
        WeapType.setOnClickListener(this);
        WeapRange.setOnClickListener(this);
        WeapAmmo.setOnClickListener(this);
        WeapDamage.setOnClickListener(this);
        try {
            WeaponStuff = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            WeaponStuff.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void loadData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        /*
         * String collected = null; FileInputStream fis = null; try { fis =
         * openFileInput(FILENAME); byte[] dataArray = new
         * byte[fis.available()]; while(fis.read(dataArray) != -1){ collected =
         * new String(dataArray); } } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { // TODO
         * Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace(); } catch (IOException
         * e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block e.printStackTrace();
         * }finally{ try { fis.close(); Weapon.setText(collected); } catch
         * (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         * e.printStackTrace(); } }
         */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to close your Button tag :

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/bACDescriptionSave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Save" /> <-- add /
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not a `valid XML`  you are not close button tag

change  it to

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/bACDescriptionSave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="Save" >  </Button>    <-----------you forgot here
        </LinearLayout>
```